# DocuSign: Can the detect when an envelope cannot be viewed by current, authenticated user via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have an application that creates an envelope via the API and stores the envelopeId, name (subject), and status.

Our application shows this envelope information and offers a "view in DocuSign" button, so that the user (who might be the sender or possibly a recipient, but maybe neither) can view the envelope in DocuSign to see its full history, or to edit it if permitted.

This button invoked createSender method in EnvelopeViews to open a browser tab on the DocuSign page.  This works fine when the user is the creator of the envelope or was given shared access to the envelope by the creator.  (Via DocuSign Admin.)

However, if the user isn't the creator (owner), createSender shows an empty editor page with the message, "you have no envelopes".

Edit: I have switched from createSender to CreateConsole, which is better: it takes the user to their home page when the envelope isn't accessible to them.

I understand the need for limiting access, but is there a way of detecting an envelope's ownership or the current user's rights to view it prior to generating and utilizing the createSend or createConsole methods?  Then we could clearly report, "You don't have permission to view this envelope" or such.

There clearly is a concept of ownership and sharing.  It is quite surprising that this information isn't available when reading the envelope's metadata.

If there is really no efficient way to know if the envelope can be viewed, I guess I'll invoke the createConsole method and let the user discover if they can view the envelope or not.

Comment: This will still be an issue until the envelope is at a terminal state, completed, void, or expired as the "Recipients" and will only see the envelope once they are ready to sign, or have been in the routing order already. How would that work if the envelope is corrected, and they were never supposed to see it if "all" were allowed in, even if they were not ready? Sadly I have stopped answering questions for users < less than 200 since it is clear they are not by in large marking questions answered.

Comment: Also, your database query from the data stored when the envelope was created by your app should be of use to determine if the call needs to be made at all, console, envelope, or any of the "views". Not apart of the db records you have concerning the envelope would allow you far more control over the experience. If you are not doing this, then I would say a key peice of the "overall" integrations is missing besides "connect". There are many ways to solve this issue without a "explict api call" to just check what you should already know except when it is changed outside your app.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want your user to be able to view/edit an envelope they have sent? Or do you want a recipient to see it? What are you trying to do? Where did you get the envelope Id?

Comment: @DavidWGrigsby thank you for your comments.

Comment: @LarryK I've edited my post, hopefully answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know an envelope's ownership. But I think below solution should give you an overview if the user can access the envelope or not (either shared with him or he is the owner of the envelope).

a. Call `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders` this will list all the folders which user has accessto, it also includes the list of the folders for other users who has shared envelopes with this user.

b. Response to above call will list all the folderIds which this user has accessto, like below sample, It will show all the folders which this user owns or shared with this user.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "ownerUserName": "AnotherUser Test",
            "ownerEmail": "anotheruseremail@gmail.com",
            "ownerUserId": "a832164e-0da7-449c-9405-be21632564a4",
            "type": "inbox",
            "name": "Inbox",
            "uri": "/folders/2980d14d-461b-4229-9ae7-b9d0c64371ea",
            "folderId": "2980d14d-461b-4229-9ae7-b9d0c64371ea"
        },
        {
            "ownerUserName": "AnotherUser Test",
            "ownerEmail": "anotheruseremail@gmail.com",
            "ownerUserId": "a832164e-0da7-449c-9405-be21632564a4",
            "type": "sentitems",
            "name": "Sent Items",
            "uri": "/folders/507050da-3817-47be-a20c-142374a50493",
            "folderId": "507050da-3817-47be-a20c-142374a50493"
        },
        {
            "ownerUserName": "OriginalUser Test",
            "ownerEmail": "amitkumar.bist+test@gmail.com",
            "ownerUserId": "87b00103-461d-487b-8928-1991dfdb8d19",
            "type": "inbox",
            "name": "Inbox",
            "uri": "/folders/b98cd590-c7b4-469a-bf7c-dd3be19d3763",
            "folderId": "b98cd590-c7b4-469a-bf7c-dd3be19d3763"
        }
    ]
}
```

c. Then call `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}` to know all the envelopes available in the folder. Check if your envelopeId is present in this list or not, if not then that user does not have access to that envelope.

Comment: Clever!  But, potentially this is a lot of data to sift through (folders for 1 + N shared users plus however many envelopes are in each) to find the one.

Comment: Yeah this is the only solution which I can think of. But ideally when creating a envelope you should save envelopeId and sender details in your database, and when anyone wants to see then always create the view from the sender's credentials/accesstoken only. But in this can you need to also save data in your DB that who all can access a specific envelope, if the one who is accessing is correctly authorized then generate the view from original sender's credentials/accesstoken only, not a clean one but then no need to make so many DS API calls.

Comment: Storing the sender's details along with the envelopeId, and using these to generate the link, seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling [Envelopes::get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) with the potential viewer's credentials. If that call succeeds then I believe they will have access to view all of the envelope's info via the DocuSign web tool.

Comment: An Account Admin can always successfully call envelopes' get API and it will never fail, but when you will try to invoke enelopeView then I assume it will not show the envelope.

Comment: I believe the API **should** be able to determine the user's ability to access an envelope in a single call, either my adding a property to the result of Envelopes::get or via a new method, such as Envelopes::getPermission.  Please accept this as a feature request.

Comment: I've reconsidered my feature request: nvelopeViews::createSender should fail when permissions are inadequate.  Why should it "successfully" return a view url that doesn't actually let you view the envelope.